# Is it possible to communicate between website and app?

Tags: android, ios, .net

When a website is implemented in an app, is it possible to open an popup in the app when clicken on a link/button in the website?

If so, what are the possibilities?

Thanks
Grtz

Comment: Could you Please explain your question in more detail.what you want ?

Comment: Yes you can do, Android Deep Link concept is there, Please explain the exact scenario,

Comment: I think what you want is the deep link, for more information see [here](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking)

Answer (score 0):

Your case I understand may have two scenarios to it. Say on the same device, click a link on browser it opens in the app much of what medium and a couple of other apps do. Second case is an independent phone and independent browser. Here I would suggest using `web sockets` to send real time data to the client app when a certain change occurs on the server side which may be caused by change in another client. Basically close to what services like `Firebase` offer but not actually the same